# Loading managed dll into AppDomain from native c++ code

Tags: .net, c++, winapi, dll, clr

I want to load managed assembly into the AppDomain from native c++ code.
If it worth something the native code is a CLR profiler so I get notification each time AppDomain is created.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to [host CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163567.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for `ICLRRuntimeHost::ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain()`. It will load an assembly into the *default* AppDomain. You asked about loading into "the" AppDomain, so presumably you don't care about other non-default AppDomains.

`ICLRRuntimeHost` is a COM interface, and thus available to native code.